# Error with shared dataset when manually download report and put into ReportViewer

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a server report that references a shared dataset on the server. It works fine if I add a `ReportViewer` to a page and set the report server URL and report path properties.

Because I need to look at the xml of the report and do some preprocessing, I:-

1. Manually download the report using: `ReportingService2010.GetItemDefinition(path)`. I then convert this to an `XDocument`.
2. Do my preprocessing - this does not touch anything to do with datasets.
3. Load the xml definition into the report viewer using:

   ```
   XDocument processedDocument;

   using (var sr = new StringReader(processedDocument.ToString()))  
   {  
        viewer.ServerReport.LoadReportDefinition(sr);  
   }
   ```

When I attempt to view the report, I see this error in the server error logs:

> *Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException:
>
>   Shared dataset definition stream does not exist.*

To get to the crux of the error, I've removed step 2 completely so that all I am doing is downloading the report, converting to xml and then loading the xml into the `ReportViewer`.

I do not get this problem when the datasets are embedded in the report.

Any ideas what is happening here?

**ETA:**

If I download the report, convert to XDocument, convert back to byte[] and then use ReportingService2010.SetItemDefinition() to save the report on the server, it displays fine in the ReportViewer (when the path is specified).

This means the problem is not in the xml<->byte[] conversions. When the ReportViewer downloads a report, using a path, it must be doing something with the referenced shared datasets that I'm not doing.

Comment: See my answer to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788313/ssrs-report-viewer-doesnt-detect-datasource/12791302#12791302
Basically, in local mode hosting application must provide all data to the report viewer

Comment: My example is using Server mode, not Local mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround.

It seems to be a problem with the relative path to the shared DataSets. I presume I would have the same problem referring to shared images on the server as well.

Here's what I intend to do:

- Download the report.
- Perform pre-processing.
- Use ReportingServices2010.CreateCatalogueItem to save a new report back on the server <del>at exactly the same location</del>, but using a temporary name.
- Use reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath to reference the new temporary report.

**ETA:**

Actually, because the DataSet path references always start at the root, I don't think you have to store the report at exactly the same location. You can create a /Temp folder that you can easily periodically clean out.